# Rotated image in ImageView

Tags: java, android

I want to show an arrow that indicates the direction towards a goal, using the orientation sensor and current GPS position. Everything works well, except that I want to rotate the arrow image in my ImageView.

The current code, which shows the arrow pointing upwards, is this:

```
ImageViewArrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow);
```

What is the best solution for showing the arrow, rotated by N degrees?

I tried this, but it gave messed up graphics:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix(); 
matrix.postRotate(Rotation);
Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
  R.drawable.arrow); 
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0,
  bitmapOrg.getWidth(),bitmapOrg.getHeight(), matrix, true); 
BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(resizedBitmap);
InfoArrow.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
InfoArrow.setImageDrawable(bmd);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you can find a tutorial

http://www.anddev.org/resize_and_rotate_image_-_example-t621.html

Comment: I tried that before posting the question, but I got wrong results. However, this is actually the solution - I just had to remove the line  InfoArrow.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);, then it looks right.

Comment: That is terribly inefficient for something that is continually updating.  For this kind of thing you really should just write a custom View that draws what you want.  There is no need to abuse a standard class like ImageView like this; writing a custom View that draws a bitmap (and applies a rotation before doing so) is pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

There is a matrix parameter in the createBitmap method that can be used for resizing and rotating the image. You could try something like the following:

```
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix(); 
    // to rotate the image bitmap use post Rotate
    matrix.postRotate(45); 


    Bitmap rotatedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0, 
                      width, height, matrix, true); `
```